# C++ std::move() performance wise with lvalues

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, std, move

I've just finished learning about lvalues, rvalues, move constructor and move operator.
I can see the added value of using move constructor with **rvalues** performance and usability wise.
But i can't see the added value of using move operator with move constructor with **lvalues** performance wise, sure there is a added value usability wise, but can't we achieve the same functionality for lvalues using some other technologies like pointers for example.
so my question is: what is the added value of using move operator with move constructor with **lvalues** performance wise.
Thanks for reading my question.

example:

```
class string{
public:
char* data;

string(){
    data = nullptr;
}

string(const char* p)
{
    size_t size = std::strlen(p) + 1;
    data = new char[size];
    std::memcpy(data, p, size);
}

 ~string()
{
    delete[] data;
}

string(const string& that)
{
    size_t size = std::strlen(that.data) + 1;
    data = new char[size];
    std::memcpy(data, that.data, size);
}

string(string&& that)
{
    data = that.data;
    that.data = nullptr;
}

string movee(string &that){
    data = that.data;
    that.data = nullptr;
}};
```

what is the difference performence wise:

```
string s1("test");
string s2(std::move(s1));

string s1("test");
string s2 = string();
s2.movee(s1);
```

In the case of rvalues, the compiler spares us the time and memory taken to reform a new object and assign the rvalue to it, and then using that new object to change the values in the moved-to object, thus increasing performance. But in the case of a lvalue object, the move operator is not increasing performance, it is increasing usability and readability of course, but it is not increasing the performance as if it was a rvalue, am I wrong?

Comment: `std::move` simply tells the compiler: "It's OK to treat this lvalue as an rvalue, and steal its contents; I don't plan to use it afterwards". Whereupon the existing mechanisms for rvalues can be applied to this lvalue, too. What would be the point of inventing a completely new, separate machinery specifically for lvalues, rather than reusing one that already exists for rvalues?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can see the ease of usability, but my question is considering performance

Comment: You can archive most things with other techniques. But adding a standardized functionality into the core of the language makes it well defined, and ideally allows the compiler to do a better job, allows static analyzers to warn you about errors, and improves maintainability.

Comment: Considering performance of what, when compared to what else?

Comment: the added value is the same as in general, you move instead of copying. Move semantics can be implemented without language support, but it is rather intrusive, hence not very desirable to use "other technologies" when the language does support it

Comment: Sure, you could use named methods and avoid the core language constructs.  It will make for more verbose and awkward and non-idiomatic (for move) syntax, but you can do it as per your example code.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the point of the movee method and the example are just to clarify the question, The point of the question is, can  we achieve the same functionality without `std::move()` or not

Comment: The issue with your question is the usage of the term "functionality".  Some would say "no, you cannot achieve the same functionality", because in a real program, your `movee` is only used if an explicit call is made, while a move constructor alone is all that's required for the compiler to take advantage of moving.

Comment: In the case of rvalues, the compiler spares us the time and memory taken to reform a new object and assign the rvalue to it, and then using that new object to change the values in the in moved-to object, thus increasing performance. But in the case of a lvalue object, the move operator is not increasing performance, it's increasing usability and readability of course, but it is not increasing the performance as if it was a rvalue, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* achieve the same functionality using indirection with pointers. Indeed, we used to, and even now that is exactly what is happening *inside* your move constructors/assignment operators!

Yes, most of the benefit when you `std::move` a variable is in the cleanliness of the code. But this is not pointless. Stealing resources with move constructors/assignment operators allows us to do so neatly, and quickly, without hacks or any performance penalties. Your code will be more maintainable and easier to rationalise about. You will be much less tempted to add an extra layer of indirection, dynamically allocating things that didn't need to be dynamically allocated, just to get code that's in any way understandable, because now there won't be *any* benefit in doing so.

But! Don't forget that your standard containers are doing this for you behind the scenes, e.g. when `std::vector` resizes. That's very valuable. If we could *only* move from temporaries, that would not be possible and we'd have a massive wasted opportunity on our hands.

Doing it with temporaries isn't really any different; it's just that it's done for you without having to type `std::move`.

Comment: Thanks for you answers, it is very informative,  but what to you mean in the last statement

Comment: @ColdHands You say you already see the benefits of moving from "rvalues". I'm saying the benefits are not really any different for "lvalues". It's just spelled differently in your code (and used less).

Comment: Are you sure that doing it with rvalues is the same as doing it with lvalues, there are a lot more optimizations happening when using it with rvalues, but other than readability and usability, is there any difference between `movee` and the move constructor?

Comment: @ColdHands _"there are a lot more optimizations happening when using it with rvalues"_ Could you name one for me?

Comment: @ColdHands _"is there any difference between movee and the move constructor?"_ That's a false comparison. `std::move` is a utility that gives you access to the move constructor. It's like asking for the difference between a cow and a farm.

Comment: I am not comparing between `std::move` and move constructor, `std::move` does nothing but casting, I am comparing performance wise between move constructor and `movee`, they both have the same functionality regarding lvalues and casted lvalues, so no it's not  _"like asking for the difference between a cow and a farm"_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218300/discussion-between-coldhands-and-asteroids-with-wings).

Comment: Your `movee` function does what a move assignment operator would do. You basically implemented `swap`. That's what a move assignment operator should use, too. The difference is that a standard container would have no idea that it exists.